# How to declare an int and double in for loop in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I tried

```
    for (int i = 0, double j = 0.0f; i <= 30; i++, j++)
```

but it didn't like that.  It said " 'j' undeclared ".  It worked if both were ints.  Is there not a way to declare it in the for loop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only use a single statement in the loop initializer. So you'll have to declare at least one of your vars outside the loop:

```
int i;
double j;
for (i = 0, j = 0.0f; i <= 30; i++, j++)
```

If it worked with two *int*s you probably used `for (int i = 0, j = 0; ...)` which is valid since only one statement (which declares multiple variables) is used.

Comment: So then how come it doesn't have a problem with  

for (int i = 0,  j = 0; i <= 30; i++, j++)

Answer (score 1):

The initializer portion of the `for` loop can only be a single statement. You can declare multiple variables of a common type in a single statement, e.g. `int i, j;`, but you can't declare multiple variables of different types this way.

If you want to limit both values to the body of the `for`-loop, you can enclose the declaration and the `for` loop in a single compound statement, like so:

```
{
    double j = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; /*test*/; /*at-end statement*/) {
        /* body */
    }
}
```

You can also work around this by using an anonymous struct (though this just obscures the point, it does do precisely what you want):

```
for (struct {int i; double j;} ctx = {0, 0.0}; /*test ctx.i or ctx.j*/; /*at-end*/) {
    /*body*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just declare them before the loop? The comma in a variable declaration is only to separate like types, and it's a confusing read, anyways. Not to mention, makes it harder to know what will happen exactly when. Btw, "++" on a float doesn't technically yield exact values (isn't guaranteed, like an int), so I'm also curious why you need to do that.

```
int i;
double j = 0.0f;
for( i=0; i<=30; i++ ) {
   j += 1.0f;
   // other stuff
}
```

Easier to read, anyways. Perhaps especially for others, as yet unfamiliar with what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a objective-c programmer, but what I know about for loops is that you cannot declare like that with a comma in between. 
`int i, double j;` is not allowed. So what you have to do is to decide to use double or integer. 
In other words, there is no way to declare like what you have done inside the parentheses of the for loop.
Use either `int i, j;` or `double i, j`!